# Automatically deploying .whl artifacts from Azure DevOps feed to Synapse spark pools

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-synapse

I want to automatically deploy artifacts (custom python packages / .whl files) from the Azure DevOps artifact feed to a Synapse spark pool.

Currently I have to manually:

- download the .whl file from the artifact feed
- upload the .whl file to the synapse workspace
- add the package/.whl to the packages of a spark pool (> "Select from workspace packages").

I have so far not found any option to do this as part of a release/pipeline in Azure DevOps or via the AzureCLI and also have not found any documentation on it. I was wondering whether anyone has found a solution concerning automating this step? It is quite cumbersome to have to do it manually.

PS: I already asked this question on the [MS forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/874459/deploying-whl-artifacts-from-azure-devops-feed-to.html), but have gotten no official answer yet.

Comment: 1. Download package from DevOps feed with task: [Download package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-package?view=azure-devops). 
2. Use "Synapse workspace deployment" task to deploy the package. Please check link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery#set-up-a-stage-task-for-azure-synapse-artifacts-deployment

Comment: The second link describes how to deploy artifacts such as pipelines, scripts, linkedServices or triggers within a Synapse Workspace via configuration of the JSON template - but nowhere does it say anything about deploying packages to spark pools... how is this supposed to help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to update the pool spark packages by using both the `Download Packages` task and the `Azure CLI` task in the release pipeline on devops.

First use the `Download Packages` task to download your feed to the pipeline `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` then use the Azure CLI to update the sparkpool.

In the Azure CLI task write in the inline command field the two following lines. Use the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` as working directory, also I recommand to check the `Use global Azure CLI configuration` checkbox.

- First command to upload your .whl to the workspace. Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cli/azure/synapse/workspace-package?view=azure-cli-latest)

  `az synapse workspace-package upload --workspace-name yourworkspace --package yourpackage.whl`
- Then upload it to the pool spark. Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cli/azure/synapse/spark/pool?view=azure-cli-latest#az-synapse-spark-pool-update).

  `az synapse spark pool update --name yourpoolspark --workspace-name yourworkspace --resource-group yourresourcegroupe --package-action Add --package yourpackage.whl`

Those two commands will add the package to your workspace and then upload it to the poolspark.

You can achieve the same things with the `Azure Powershell` task on a Windows agent. Here is the doc to explore : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-packages-outside-ui#manage-packages-through-azure-powershell-cmdlets).

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Do you have another tip on how to pass the name of the latest package to the Azure CLI task? I can set the version to `latest` in the DownloadPackage task, but I need to reference the specific file name in the Azure CLI

Comment: right now I managed to do it by using `$file_name = Get-ChildItem *.whl` and `echo $file_name.name` , but Im sure there is a better way

Comment: What you Can do is convert the release pipeline in a build pipeline by copying the yaml code of the tasks and add a new stage. By doing that you can access the package name as a variable. If the pipeline producing your feed is a build pipeline (with yaml code) you can merge the yaml codes and share the feed name between the yaml stages

Comment: Ohh, fancy idea. Thanks!